# PHP get number from other number

Tags: php, string, substring, str-replace

I get data from this code.

```
foreach ($datas as $data){
    echo $data['product_number']."<br>";
}
```

Then it will show the data like :

```
MP/9998/00012
00089
12009
290989
```

But I want to change my data become

```
12
120
89
12009
290989
```

I edit the question. Here's my question before:

I have this array

```
$data = ["00012", "00120", "00089", "12009", "290989"].
```

This array have contain at least 5 character. How can I get that array data become

```
[12, 120, 89, 12009, 290989]
```

Thank You.

Comment: Try `array_map` with `intval`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple use `array_map` and `intval`

```
$data= array('00012','00120','00089','12009','290989');
$new = array_map('intval',$data); //intval function applied to each element in the array 

print_r($new);
```

**Update 1:** Apply `intval`

```
foreach ($datas as $data){
    echo intval($data['product_number'])."<br>";
}
```

**Update 2:** use `filter_var`

```
$str = 'MP/000090';
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo intval($int);
```

Comment: @JYoThI, hey thanks for your solution. But when i try that code, it doesn't work. I've edit the question and make it more detail. Thank You,

Comment: @JYoThI, great. it's work. But is it possible if there's one of data `MP/000090` and i want to get just 90 ?

Comment: @JYoThI it's great!! but sorry i want to ask you again, because i just find that there's MP/9998/002328 in that data. How can i get just 2328 ? Thank much to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153313/discussion-between-jyothi-and-adn).

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
<?php

$data = array("00012", "00120", "00089", "12009", "290989" );
foreach( $data as $v )
{
     echo ltrim($v, "0") . "\n";
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/1Zr6d)

***Output***

```
12
120
89
12009
290989
```

Answer (score 0):

This will always return your last string of numbers (omitting any preceding zeros) in each element:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/afd7ebd4c863a407417ecf22da5926d09c6b4351))

```
$data=array('00012','00120','00089','12009','290989','MP/000090','MP/9998/0023028');
$data=array_map(function($v){return preg_match('~0*\K\d+$~',$v,$out)?$out:'fail';},$data);
var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '12',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '120',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '89',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '12009',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => '290989',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => '90',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => '23028',
  ),
)
```